# Value parsing from XML tag

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sh

```
cat /home/user/my.xml | grep -e productVersion | awk {'print $2'}
```

It parses data from file `my.xml` where I have a tag such like this:

```
<product productVersion="10.2.14.0" Type="test" Sub="0.3">
```

and finally I have a good result:

```
productVersion="10.2.14.0"
```

But on any oldest versions XML at others desktops, column can be not $2 and $3, and $4 etc. Of cause I tried to do ID ELSE, it works but I really couldn't know each column on each PC.

May be is it some function or trick for example where I can put `productVersion=*` and where I can see result from tag `productVersion="10.2.14.0"`?

Comment: `grep -o 'productVersion="[^"]*"'` Or use an XML parser. And by the way, that's not a *tag*, it's an *attribute*. And there's [no need for `cat`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat).

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes sorry, of course attribute :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you asked for an awk answer:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/productVersion="[^"]+"/){ print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) }' file
productVersion="10.2.14.0"
```

or in gawk:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/productVersion="[^"]+"/,a){ print a[0] }' file
productVersion="10.2.14.0"
```

Note that the ticks go OUTSIDE of the awk script (`awk '<whole script>'`), not inside the curly brackets `awk {'<rest of script>'}`), since the ticks are the script delimiters and the curly brackets are just part of the script.

Comment: Thanks, Added in my memories too

Answer (score 2):

Use a proper parser to extract information from the XML.

```
xmllint my.xml --xpath '//product/@productVersion'
```

Comment: Good answer, but I have TinyCore linux where this command doesn't exist. Anyway thanks

Comment: @mulrus: Can't you install `libxml2`?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Huge quantity desktops without connected repository to Internet. And TinyCore also different version. grep best way.

Comment: Then just hope you never get an XML with commented parts and similar tricks.

Comment: No I got. It's enough for me. XML no so huge. I have already done my task what I wanted.